# How to detect a youtube commercial skip

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to detect if a commercial was skipped or not in youtube?

(if a user clicks on the skip button)

Also, is there a way to force a youtube video to always have an ad in it?

Comment: I assume you are the owner of the channel. Can't you grab your analytic statistics, and subtract the amount of ad views from your total amount of views?

Comment: I've never not clicked on the skip button.

Comment: I am not an owner of a channel. I am just wondering if it is possible in any way to know whether an ad was skipped before watching a video.